# Pass information on a dropdown from one jsp page to another

Tags: jsp

I have an index.jsp page as follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.io.*" import="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory,javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder,org.w3c.dom.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="annotation.jsp">
        <body>
            <form method="get" action="annotation.jsp">
                Michael

                <div class="dropdown">
                    Owen
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <br>
                        <input name = "gap" type="checkbox" value="definition">definition
                        <br>
                        <input name = "gap" type="checkbox" value="explanation">explanation
                    </div>
                </div>

                is an English former footballer who played as a striker for Liverpool, Real Madrid, Newcastle United, Manchester United and Stoke City, as well as for the England national team.

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and another annotation.jsp file as follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.io.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Annotation</title>
<body>
    <%
        String req = request.getParameterValues("gap");
            out.println(req);
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, if I `mouse-over` a certain word (in this case, the word "Owen"), a drop-down will appear with two `check-boxes` (definition and explanation). Consider, I selected the check-box "definition". The selected check-box information, I can pass to another jsp page using `<form method="get" action="annotation.jsp">`. At annotation.jsp I can collect these sent information using `<%String req = request.getParameter("gap");%>`. But, are there any means to pass the word (which is "Owen" for this case) for which the type of the gap (definition) is being selected? How to do that?

Comment: hard to understand, story about dropdown, html code (probably invalid) with checkbox. Code is MAIN way of communication between programmers

Comment: @Jacek Cz they are jsp pages and I tried to explain a little more with this edit. Please provide solutions if possible.

Comment: are You sure two elements with the same name "gap" ?

Comment: Yes, because I have to select only one of them

Comment: no comment, EOT for me